# JQueryUI Tooltip settings ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I can't get JQueryUI to pay any attention to the tooltip settings I am trying to apply

```
var li = jQuery('<li title="test">test</li>');
jQuery(myUl).append(li);

jQuery(li).tooltip({
    track: true,
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "bottom",
        using: function (position, feedback) {
            $( this ).css( position );
            $("<div>").addClass("arrow")
        }
    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).attr('title');
    }
});
```

I know that the tooltip() function is being called because I can comment it out and the display reverts back to the standard tooltip, but nothing in the parameters makes any difference to the display. My first priority is to get the content to appear on multiple lines, for that I have added `<br />` tags at the right places. But so far they always get displayed to the user.

Help!

Comment: It appears to be a user error. I had no idea that Bootstrap also provided a Tooltip function and it is taking priority here. Once I started using Bootstrap Tooltip options they were used just fine

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a user error. I had no idea that Bootstrap also provided a Tooltip function and it is taking priority here. Once I started using Bootstrap Tooltip options they were used just fine

Comment: +1 I've lost over an hour because of exact same reason. Thanks for sharing and saving me several more hours!

Answer (score 0):

remove the line:

```
var li = jQuery('<li title="test">test</li>');
```

add `<li>` element directly to jQuery:

```
jQuery('li').tooltip({
   track: true,
   position: {
    my: "left top",
    at: "bottom",
    using: function (position, feedback) {
        $( this ).css( position );
        $("<div>").addClass("arrow")
    }
  },
  content: function () {
    return $(this).attr('title');
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm creating these li elements as I go and according to the spec you can pass an element in like that. I missed out the line about appending the element, I'll update the question. Note though that the tooltip() function is being run and is modifying the tool tip on these elements, it's the settings for those tooltips that I have problems with